Issues attaching xlsx file to docs using spire.doc.free java
iam not able to attach OLE xlsx file to word document using spire doc java  , but i was sucessful in attaching PDF to word document. Attached Code screenshot. Please help here.
DocPicture pdfIcon = new DocPicture(oarDoc);
            pdfIcon.loadImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons8-excel-is-a-spreadsheet-developed-by-microsoft-48.png"));
            //pdfIcon.loadImage("C:\\Workspace\\bds-offers-in-hours\\src\\main\\resources\\Test.xlsx");
            //Insert a PDF file to the Word document as an OLE object
            //InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Test.xlsx");
            //InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("C:\\\\Workspace\\\\bds-offers-in-hours\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\Test.xlsx");
            par.appendOleObject("C:\\\\\\\\Workspace\\\\\\\\bds-offers-in-hours\\\\\\\\src\\\\\\\\main\\\\\\\\resources\\\\\\\\Test.xlsx", pdfIcon, OleObjectType.Excel_Worksheet);
            //Save to another file
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oarDoc.saveToFile(outputStream1, FileFormat.Docx);
            byte[] oarBytes = outputStream1.toByteArray();
            return oarBytes;

i was expecting to to attach xlsx file
